# Alocating array positions to splinted words after using the strtok function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char pch[]="encrypt young;double royal;double man;double timothy45r";
    char *cmd;
    char *ptr;

    for (cmd = strtok_r(pch,";",&ptr); cmd; cmd = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &ptr)) {
        char *word;
        char *ptr2;
        char cwd[524];

        for (word = strtok_r(cmd, " ", &ptr2); word; word = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptr2)) {
            printf("%s\n",word);

            if (strcmp(word,"double")==0)
            {
                char *word2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptr2);
                strcpy(cwd, word2);
                strcat(cwd, word2);
                printf(" %s\n", cwd);
            }
            if(strcmp(word,"encrypt")==0) 
            {
                char *word2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptr2);
                strcpy(cwd, word2);
                printf(" %s\n", cwd);
            }
        }
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Above is my code, I wanted to create an array that can store values of `word2` i.e 
`array[0]="young"`, `array[1]="royal"`, `array[2]="man"`......and so on after splinting them into a single word. The reason was to compare the string lengths of those words(`word2`) and then I assign them priorities according to one with the least length,but problem came in when I wanted to compare the lengths I couldn't relocate the positions of the splinted words thus comparing becoming impossible, so am requesting if there is a solution to the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this ->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH_STRING 256
#define MAX_ENTRIES 1024
const char *keys[] = {"double","encrypt"};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int numKeys = sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]);
    char myData[numKeys][MAX_ENTRIES][MAX_LENGTH_STRING]; //malloc this in real code depending on size.. you dont want a Stack overflow ;-)
    int keyCounter[numKeys];
    char pch[]="encrypt young;double royal;double man;double timothy45r";
    char *substring = strtok(pch, ";");
    while (substring != NULL) {
        for (int x=0;x<numKeys;x++) {
            if (!strncmp(keys[x], substring, strlen(keys[x]))) {
                printf("Key: %s found containing string -> %s\n", keys[x],substring+strlen(keys[x])+1);
                if (strlen(substring+strlen(keys[x])+1) >= MAX_LENGTH_STRING-1) {
                    //Do something about the string is too long.
                }
                strncpy(&myData[x][keyCounter[x]++][0], substring+strlen(keys[x])+1, strlen(substring+strlen(keys[x])+1));
                if (keyCounter[x] == MAX_ENTRIES) {
                    //Do something about more than max entries for the given prefix
                }
            }
        }
        substring = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
    //Here you can move search sort shuffle your data/arrays -> myData
    //number of entries for the given array is found in -> keyCounter
    //this is just a example printing all 'encrypt' key's values
    printf("Number of 'encrypt' strings %d, and they are -> \n",keyCounter[1]);
    for (int x=0;x<keyCounter[1];x++) printf("%s \n",&myData[1][x][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

It's fairly simple and you can dynamically create new keys and modify the code to your needs. For example throw in a 'else' if a key is not found and things like that.

**EDIT 1**
Did add storing into arrays.
**EDIT 2**
Code clean up and added example.

/Anders

Comment: the code works fine, but am really failing to understand how it's saving the last elements in the array ,..basically this part substring+7, is it an array that holds the 1st value which i can use to  compare with the other arrays or its just an element holder in memory?

Comment: More so i want to pick a particular string i.e string at position one and i compare it with all strings which have been splinted in terms of length